# Only display if more than one object in Raiils 5.0 .each loop

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

I have a product model that belongs to and has many Variations.  On my Product show page, I have the Variations in a top-of-page slider.  I also have thumbnails of the associated Variations beneath the slider.  What I am trying to do is hide, or not show the thumbnail if there is only 1 Variation as it is redundant to have the only Variation in the slider as well as a single thumbnail.

The code below is what I am attempting to do but it doesn't work--see `<% if v >= 1 %>`

**views/products/_variation-thumbs.html.erb**

```
<% @product.variations.each do |v| %>
  <% if v >= 1 %>
    <% if v.photo_one.present? %>
      <div class="col-md-2" style="padding: 0 7px">
        ...
      </div>
    <% end %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess you could do something like this:

```
@product.joins(:variations).group('products.id').having('count(product) > 1')
```

Give a try and see if it works for you. Good luck!